# Proof of the PRESS residual

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, error

I'm not sure where the expression  $\
e_{i,-i}=\frac{e_{i}}{1-H_{ii}}$came from, for $H_{ii}$ the i'th diagonal entry of the *hat matrix*. Could anyone please guide me to prove that the LHS would eventually yield the RHS? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Rob Hyndman has a nice explanation of this on his "Hyndsight" blog. The relevant post is [here.](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/loocv-linear-models/)